# View Pager in Activity

Tags: android, android-viewpager

I want to slide acivities with view pager not by gesture Listener in android.
I am able to add view pager on image view but not on activities so please help me ...
Thanks in advance!

Comment: You add Fragments to the ViewPager, not Activities. Have a look at the example that Eclipse creates when you select "swipe navigation" as template and you'll get the idea.

Comment: You must use fragments within the view pager. not the activities itself. if you want to know how you could do that, i can paste that as an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use fragments for each view in a pager.

write the below code in `onCreate()` method of the `FragmentActivity`.

```
List<Fragment> fragments = new Vector<Fragment>();

//for each fragment you want to add to the pager
Bundle page = new Bundle();
page.putString("url", url);
fragments.add(Fragment.instantiate(this,MyFragment.class.getName(),page));

//after adding all the fragments write the below lines

this.mPagerAdapter  = new PagerAdapter(super.getSupportFragmentManager(), fragments);

mPager.setAdapter(this.mPagerAdapter);
```

A sample fragment definition:

```
public class MyFragment extends Fragment {


public static MyFragment newInstance(String imageUrl) {

final MyFragment mf = new MyFragment ();

    final Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putString("somedata", "somedata");
    mf.setArguments(args);

    return mf;
}

public MyFragment() {}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    String data = getArguments().getString("somedata");
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate and locate the main ImageView
    final View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.my_fragment_view, container, false);
    //... 
    return v;
}
```

Edit(Addition): FragmentPagerAdapter

```
public class MyFragmentAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

public static int pos = 0;

private List<Fragment> myFragments;

public MyFragmentAdapter(FragmentManager fm, List<Fragment> myFrags) {
    super(fm);
    myFragments = myFrags;
}

@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {

    return myFragments.get(position);

}

@Override
public int getCount() {

    return myFragments.size();
}

@Override
public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {

    setPos(position);

    String PageTitle = "";

    switch(pos)
    {
        case 0:
                PageTitle = "page 1";
                break;
        case 1:
                PageTitle = "page 2";
                break;
        case 2:
                PageTitle = "page 3";
                break;
        case 3:
                PageTitle = "page 4";
                break;
        case 4:
                PageTitle = "page 5";
                break;
        case 5: 
                PageTitle = "page 6";
                break;
        case 6:
                PageTitle = "page 7";
                break;
    }
    return PageTitle;
}

public static int getPos() {
    return pos;
}

 public static void setPos(int pos) {
    MyFragmentAdapter.pos = pos;
 }
}
```

Comment: thanks sir , its a very good example but can you please add the PageAdapter code also...

Comment: Saw your comment now. PagerAdapter has been added. call me santhosh. Happy coding.

Answer (score 1):

Use  [overridePendingTransition](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#overridePendingTransition%28int,%20int%29) like this

```
startActivity(YourNewActivity);
overridePendingTransition(R.anim.right_to_left,
                            R.anim.left_to_right);
```

**right_to_left.xml**

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shareInterpolator="false" >

    <translate
        android:duration="300"
        android:fromXDelta="100%"
        android:fromYDelta="0%"
        android:toXDelta="0%"
        android:toYDelta="0%" />

</set>
```

**left_to_right.xml**

```
<translate
    android:duration="300"
    android:fromXDelta="0%"
    android:fromYDelta="0%"
    android:toXDelta="-100%"
    android:toYDelta="0%" />
```

Answer (score 1):

`ViewPager` only holds `views` not `activity` optionally supported by `fragments`,holding `activity` inside another `activity` is officially depreciated.